# slow QFileDialog in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

PyQt4 seems to use the native MacOS file selector widget when using QFileDialog. However, when using the spotlight feature in that widget to search for files, the whole window seems to hang until the search completes. Outside of PyQt4, the Mac file dialog stays responsive while searching, presumably because the search happens on a separate execution thread.

Is there any way to keep the QFileDialog widget responsive within PyQt4?